# How can I place contents on the body of this site layout without making it look like it's floating?

Tags: website-design, layout, search, placement, contextual-menu

I am a programmer and I need a designer's expert advice regarding the website layout I am currently working on.

Here is the layout to start with:

[image: layout mockup]
<sup>Click image for full resolution</sup>

I have a full width header with the following contents:

- login
- logo
- choose country
- main navigation
- sub navigation

I need help on how to place contents on the body without making it look like it's floating. If I have to change the body layout then please tell me what would the best color scheme if I would have to place a border. But, if its possible not to place a border (just like a Facebook profile) then better.

This will be the master page of all layouts. The body may have one to three column layout. content wise It would be something like (combination)

- http://courses.sitepoint.com/
- http://courses.sitepoint.com/gettingstartedblogging
- http://www.odesk.com/
- http://www.odesk.com/login.php
- http://worldwidelearn.com
- http://events.nationalgeographic.com/

To summarize the features:

- an online directory (w/ search and advanced search)
- offers services for 4 types of users
- offers other services not directly part of the site
- has an events page
- a feedback form
- careers page

Comment: What do you mean by 'not floating'

Answer (score 1):

You chose a difficult color, as almost anything that you put onto that background will look like it's casting a shadow. I would recommend altering the background color only for the central area, and only slightly in order to accommodate the content.

Answer (score 1):

to make not look like floating you need to make that body layout is part of header, in your case, your header is look too separate with content becase you add stroke and shadow on header layer.

i suggest to remove a stroke and shadow, just a plain white so header and body look paint on same canvas. you can use a line or other color background and placing content on center to make impression that is the content layout like http://courses.sitepoint.com/